# Table with editable columns and pagination in a web page

Tags: jquery, editing, tabular

I want to create a table with editable columns and pagination. I tried Jquery but I couldn't get the proper result. I don't find any proper package to do this. Please help me with any reference.

Comment: What did you tried so far ?? Include that , " code for me " have no place at SO

Answer (score 2):

Use JS plugin: [DataTables](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).

This has everything.

Answer (score 0):

use this [Link](http://demos.9lessons.info/EditDeletePagination/) live demo

[Link](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/live-table-edit-delete-with-pagination.html) it has brief tutorial for the Table with editable columns and pagination in a web page

**Live Table Edit, Delete with Pagination using Jquery** i